# Group by number of occurrences based on the result of a group by query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, aggregate-functions

Imagine a table posts like this

```
posts
---

id
user_id
title
```

If I want to print out each user with the total number of posts, I might do this

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as total_posts FROM posts GROUP BY user_id
```

The result will be something like this:

```
user_id | total_posts
=====================
1       | 5
2       | 2
5       | 3
8       | 3
```

Now, what if I want to group by the total_posts? So I'm looking for a result like this:

```
total_posts | number_of_users
=============================
5       | 1
2       | 1
3       | 2
```

Is it possible to do this via MySQL? I'm solving this currently by using Laravel's collection, but it requires mapping through every row of the `user_id | total_posts` table, which can be huge, thus can be taxing to memory.

Comment: Are you using an ORM like Eloquent? You should perhaps tag it too so you could get answers that would tell you know to use it to make it create the SQL forpas suggests

Comment: I was but it's not quite performant, that's why I was searching for MySQL solution and the accepted answer solves my problem.

Comment: But all Eloquent (is supposed to) does is take some PHP and churn out an SQL, then run the SQL, get the results and pack them into objects for you - it can't be any faster or slower if you cause it to churn out the same SQL as the raw..

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I misunderstood the question. I was thinking of Laravel's collection helper functions, which required the full data to be loaded onto the memory, that's why it's not performant. Yeah, I was looking for the MySQL solution but I adapted it to the Laravel query builder (could also use Eloquent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT total_posts,
       COUNT(*) number_of_users
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, 
         COUNT(*) total_posts 
  FROM posts 
  GROUP BY user_id
) t
GROUP BY total_posts
ORDER BY total_posts DESC;
```

or, for MySql 8.0+:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       COUNT(*) total_posts,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COUNT(*)) number_of_users
FROM posts 
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY total_posts DESC;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e74969d9faf0c82489263058255d5b50).

Comment: Ah thanks! And it's very fast as well.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a solution in Laravel, this is what I end up with

```
$posts = DB::query()
    ->fromSub(function ($query) {
        $query->from('posts')
            ->selectRaw('user_id, COUNT(*) as total_posts')
            ->groupBy('user_id');
    }, 't')
    ->selectRaw('total_posts, COUNT(*) number_of_users')
    ->groupBy('total_posts')
    ->orderBy('total_posts', 'asc')
    ->get();
```